# Mobile Nav doesn't trigger in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari

I've built out a mobile navigation that uses javascript to add a class "showtime" to the navigation. This showtime class sets the opacity to 1 and visibility to visible. It works great in Chrome, however it does nothing in Safari and Firefox and I'm unsure why. Here is the site:

https://vamediation.squarespace.com

Here is the Javascript

```
// MOBILE NAVIGATION
function mobileNav() {
  var trigger = document.querySelector('#menuTrigger');
  var menu = document.querySelector('.main-navigation');
  var closeNode = document.querySelector('#menuClose');

  trigger.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (menu.className !== 'showtime') {
      menu.classList.add('showtime');
    }
  });

  closeNode.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (menu.className !== 'showtime') {
      menu.classList.remove('showtime');
    }
  });
}

mobileNav();
```

And the showtime class:

```
.showtime {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

I assume there is something wrong with the javascript since I don't see it adding the showtime class. I'm not getting anything helpful in the Console either. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The function is never called. Wrap it inside of a (function....)(); so it runs on page load.

```
(function mobileNav() {
  var trigger = document.querySelector('#menuTrigger');
  var menu = document.querySelector('.main-navigation');
  var closeNode = document.querySelector('#menuClose');

  trigger.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (menu.className !== 'showtime') {
      menu.classList.add('showtime');
    }
  });

  closeNode.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (menu.className !== 'showtime') {
      menu.classList.remove('showtime');
    }
  });
})();
```

Comment: I am calling it. Just updated my code to reflect that.  It works in Chrome just fine, just not Safari and Firefox.